# C++ Function Alters Value of Passed Parameter

Tags: c++

I have a simple swapping function to take an integer array, and return a new array with swapped values.

```
int* Node::dataSwap(int *data, int n_index, int swap_index){
    
    printDatt(data);
    int *path = data;
    int swapped = data[n_index];
    int to_swap = data[swap_index];
    path[n_index] = to_swap;
    path[swap_index] = swapped;
    printDatt(data);
    
    return path;
    
}
```

However, the reference to the original data is being altered by this function. The output looks something like this (printing the *should be the same* data to console).

```
0, 1, 2
 3, 4, 5 
 6, 7, 8

0, 1, 2
 3, 4, 8
 6, 7, 5
```

Why is "data" being changed when I am not changing it? Is "path" a reference to the actual mem addr of "data"?

Comment: `path` is litterally a **pointer** equal to the pointer `data`. Since the two pointers are equal, they point to the same region of memory.

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` that will make your life much easier

Answer (score 2):

The type of the argument `data` and the local variable `path` is **`int *`**. You can read this as "pointer to int".

A pointer is a variable holding a memory address. Nothing more, nothing less. Since you set `path = data`, those two pointers are equal.

In your mind, `data` is an array. But that's not what the function `dataSwap` is seeing. To the function `dataSwap`, its argument `data` is just a pointer to an int. This int is the first element of your array. You accessed elements of the array using `data[n_index]`; but that's just a synonym for `*(data + n_index)`.

How to remedy to your problem?

### The C way: `malloc` and `memcpy`

Since you want to return a new array, you should return a new array. To do this, you should allocate a new region of memory with `malloc`, and then copy the values of the original array to the new region of memory, using `memcpy`.

Note that it is impossible to do this using only the current arguments of the function, since none of those arguments indicate the size of the array:

- `data` is a pointer to the first element of the array;
- `n_index` is the index of one of the elements in the array;
- `swap_index` is the index of another element in the array.*

So you should add a fourth element to the function, `int size`, to specify how many elements are in the array. You can use `size` as argument to `malloc` and `memcpy`, or to write a for loop iterating over the elements of the array.

New problem arising: if you call `malloc` to allocate new memory, then the user will have to call `free` to free the memory at some point.

C++ has the cool keyword `new` whose syntax is somewhat lighter than the syntax of `malloc`. But this doesn't solve the main problem; if you allocate new memory with the keyword `new`, then the user will have to free the memory with the keyword `delete` at some point.

Urgh, so much burden!

But this was the C way. A good rule of thumb in C++ is: **never** handle arrays manually. The standard library has `std::vector` for that. There are situations where using `new` might be the best solution; but in most simple cases, it isn't.

### The C++ way: `std::vector`

Using the class `std::vector` from the standard library, your code becomes:

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> Node::dataSwap(std::vector<int> data, int n_index, int swap_index)
{
    std::vector<int> new_data = data;
    int swapped = data[n_index];
    int to_swap = data[swap_index];
    new_data[n_index] = to_swap;
    new_data[swap_index] = swapped;

    return (new_data);
}
```

No `malloc`, no `new`, no `free` and no `delete`. The class `std::vector` handles all that internally. You don't need to manually copy the data either; the initialisation `new_data = data` calls the copy constructor of class `std::vector` and does that for you.

Avoid using `new` as much as you can; use a class that handles all the memory internally, like you would expect it in a higher-level language.

Or, even simpler:

### The C++ way: `std::vector` and `std::swap`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> Node::dataSwap(std::vector<int> data, int n_index, int swap_index)
{
    std::vector<int> new_data = data;
    std::swap(new_data[n_index], new_data[swap_index]);

    return (new_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Is "path" a reference to the actual mem addr of "data"?*

Yes! In order to create a *new* array that is a *copy* of the passed data (only with one pair of values swapped over), then your function would need to create the new array (that is, allocate data for it), copy the passed data into it, then perform the swap. The function would then return the address of that ***new*** data, which should be freed later on, when it is no longer needed.

However, in order to do this, you would need to also pass the *size* of the data array to the function.

One way to do this, using 'old-style' C++, is with the `new` operator. With the added 'size' parameter, your function would look something like this:

```cpp
int* Node::dataSwap(int *data, int n_index, int swap_index, int data_size)
{    
    printDatt(data);
    int *path = new int[data_size]; // Create new array...
    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; ++i) path[i] = data[i]; // ... and copy data
    int swapped = data[n_index];
    int to_swap = data[swap_index];
    path[n_index] = to_swap;
    path[swap_index] = swapped;
    printDatt(data);    
    return path; // At some point later on, your CALLING code would "delete[] path"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! New to CPP, and tried this without allocating the specific size of the path int[size]. Explicitly declaring the size of variables is not something I am accustomed to in prior languages.

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the memory at which the pointer *path* point and that is *data*. I think try to understand better how the pointers works will help you. :)

Then you can use the swap function from the std library:

```
std::swap(data[n_index], data[swap_index]);
```

It will make your code nicer.